# In a list , What is the difference between mapping to string and convert to string in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, list

Using Python 3, I tried to join the elements of list by converting it to string. It is said that to join all the elements of a list all the elements must be converted to a string. So I just converted the whole list to a string and tried to join the list but it did not give desired output.

```
l = [1,2,3]
print("L type ",type(l))
print("Type of element ",type(l[0]))
d = str(l)
print("D type ",type(d))
print("Joining d ","".join(d))
print("D[0] type ",type(d[0]))
f = "".join(map(str,(l)))
print("F is ",f)
e = "".join(str(l))
print("E is ",e)
```

The output is :

```
L type  <class 'list'>
Type of element  <class 'int'>
D type  <class 'str'>
Joining d  [1, 2, 3]
D[0] type  <class 'str'>
F is  123
E is  [1, 2, 3]
```

But when I mapped each of the elements of the list to the string it gave the proper answer by joining the string.
But if I converted the whole list to string , and each element of list is a string Eg:(D[0] type  <class 'str'>) why it didnt join the elements ?
And if I converted elements to string at the time of joining it just returns the original list back again.

Where it differs to use map ?
So can anyone please explain What is the difference between mapping to string and convert to string ?
What is the basic criteria to join a list ?

I need anyone to explain What is the difference between mapping to string and convert to string ?
What is the basic criteria to join a list ?

Comment: The code does not match the output.

Comment: *"I just converted **the whole list** to **a** string and tried to join the list but it did not give desired output."*. As you said you "converted" your list to a **single string**, what were you expecting to join?

Comment: When you `print` some list, you don't expect the string that gets printed to be the concatenation of the string representation of its items, do you? So you get a representation of the list with square brackets and commas, and you're happy with it...

Comment: Code is not matching the output

Answer (score 0):

Converting a list to a string gives you a single string -- the same string that you get when you `print` a list, with `[` on the ends and `,` separating the elements.

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> str(a)
'[1, 2, 3]'
```

In the above REPL session, `a` is a list, and `str(a)` is a string that represents the list.  (Note the quotes!)

If you `join` a string with `''` as the seperator, you just get the same string back.  It doesn't matter what the string is.

```
>>> ''.join(str(a))
'[1, 2, 3]'
>>> ''.join("foo")
'foo'
```

If you `join` it with a separator that's not an empty string, it's easier to see what's going on -- we're just taking each character of the string and inserting the separators in between them.  The reason `join` behaves this way with a string is because a string is itself an iterable of strings (its individual characters).

```
>>> '-'.join("foo")
'f-o-o'
>>> '-'.join('[1, 2, 3]')
'[-1-,- -2-,- -3-]'
>>> '-'.join(str(a))
'[-1-,- -2-,- -3-]'
```

If you `map` the `str` function over a list, you get a list with each *individual* element transformed into a string.  A `map` object itself doesn't have a useful string representation, but you can convert a `map` into a `list`, which does.

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> map(str, a)
<map object at 0x000002D6118DA9E0>
>>> list(map(str, a))
['1', '2', '3']
```

Again, note the quotes -- `1` is an `int`, and `'1'` is a `str`.

If we `join` a list of strings, we get all of the individual strings combined into a single string:

```
>>> ''.join(['1', '2', '3'])
'123'
```

and we can `join` a `map` in exactly the same way without converting it to a `list` first:

```
>>> ''.join(map(str, a))
'123'
```